# JSON inside column DataFrame

Tags: python, sql, json, pandas, postgresql

I'm trying to make a **bulk insert** of a dataframe, my table in Postgres has a field type **JSON** and I want to insert raw JSON on it, but when I'm trying to make it, python change from double quote to `"` to single quote `'` and it technically destroys my JSON column inside of DataFrame, I'm looking just a way to make this bulk insert.

First I'm getting my data in json format, next I make the a Dataframe for data manipulation and cleaning and finally I want to insert bulk this DF in Postgres.

`df = pd.DataFrame(response['data'])`

and this is how python transforma my JSON from
`{ "age_max": 44, "age_min": [20,30] }`
to:
`{ 'age_max': 44, 'age_min': [20,30] }`

Comment: tried with `json.dumps(your_data)` ? `{ 'age_max': 44, 'age_min': [20,30] }` seems python `dict`. `json.dumps({ 'age_max': 44, 'age_min': [20,30] })` will give you JSON string `'{ "age_max": 44, "age_min": [20,30] } '`

Comment: why are you using a Dataframe if you're working with JSON? Do you have other columns with tabular data?

Comment: @el_oso I have tabular data, and inside of a column I have JSON, how can I insert it on Postgres? In postgres I have a JSON type column too.

Answer (score 0):

pandas has automagically converted the json into a dictionary object. You can easily convert a dictionary to json using `dumps` from the built in `json` module.

```py
import requests
from json import dumps

import pandas
import psycopg2

#sample dataset 
df = pandas.DataFrame.from_dict(
{'date': {0: '2021-02-16',
  1: '2021-02-15',
  2: '2021-02-14',
  3: '2021-02-13',
  4: '2021-02-12'},
 'name': {0: 'East Midlands',
  1: 'East Midlands',
  2: 'East Midlands',
  3: 'East Midlands',
  4: 'East Midlands'},
 'cases': {0: {'new': 174, 'cumulative': 294582},
  1: {'new': 1477, 'cumulative': 294408},
  2: {'new': 899, 'cumulative': 292931},
  3: {'new': 898, 'cumulative': 292032},
  4: {'new': 1268, 'cumulative': 291134}}}
)

df['json'] = df['cases'].apply(dumps) #create new series running the function json.dumps against each element in the series
p = df[['date', 'name', 'json']].values.tolist() #create parameter list

con = db_connection() #replace with your db connection function or  psycopg2.connect()

csr = con.cursor()
sql = """insert into corona (date, name, json) values (%s, %s, %s)"""
csr.executemany(sql, params=p)
con.commit()
con.close()
```